# nuget.exe in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have VS2017 and VS2019 on my machine.  I have a lot of nuget references that are missing (yellow icon) in VS2019 Solution Explorer.  I've tried doing a Restore Nuget Packages and I see:

```
All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.0560466
========== Finished ==========
```

I went into the Package Manager Console and tried to do a:

```
nuget restore MySolution.sln
```

and get a

```
nuget : The term 'nuget' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path 
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

I looked around on my hard drive and only see nuget.exe existing in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\SqlChangeAutomation\OctoPack\build\NuGet.exe

Why doesn't it also exist under 2019?

Thanks

Comment: Because Visual Studio can simply use the client library, https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Client/, not necessarily nuget.exe.

Comment: Sometimes, Visual Studio will "see" the missing references if you click on them  (the yellow ones), under the References option for a project.

Comment: As far as l know, if you want to use nuget.exe in Package Manage Console, you should set the path of `nuget.exe` which you can download from the Marcus's link into PATH of the environment variables. If the answer does help, please consider accepting it. It is just a reminder:)

Comment: Package manager console, use the powershell commands
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/powershell-reference

Answer (score 10):

you can download the Nuget.exe from [here](https://www.nuget.org/downloads).

Copy the Nuget.exe somewhere where you keep your tools. Then I recommend entering the location where you saved the Nuget.exe in the PATH system variable.

I would try to clear the nuget cache. You do this with the following command:

```
nuget locals all -clear
```

This ensures that all packages are downloaded again.

You cannot call Nuget.exe in the Package Manager Console. To do this, you have to open a console session and change to your solution directory to execute the desired command.

```
nuget restore MySolution.sln
```

Above all, it is also very helpful if you browse the Nuget documentation pages a little. You can find them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/).

I hope I could help you a little with it and guide you on a possible path.

Best wishes